# Anyone know how to solve this error breakout?

Tags: iphone, xcode

[http://imgur.com/5c3tQ.png](https://imgur.com/5c3tQ.png)

Anyone know why this happens? All the code is perfectly done. It is just that I moved from Xcode 3.2.2 to 3.2.3 (I modified the project settings as well).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some framework of yours isn't properly linked. Have you checked those?